# How to solve a difference equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

So I have the difference equation $4y_{k+1} = 2y_k$.

I need to solve this equation, first with the initial condition $y_0 = 0$ and then with the initial condition $y_0 = 2$.

The professor wrote on the answer sheet that applying iteratively the recurrence relation it is easy to check that:

$y_k= (1/2)^k y_0 $.

Since I missed the lecture where he explained this, can somebody explain how to come about with this question?

I imagine that once I get the equation, then the initial condition $y_0 = 0$ gives us the particular solution $y_k = 0$. Thus the other initial condition $y_0 = 2$ is verified by the solution $y_k = 2(1/2)^k$.

Any help on how to get to the equation $y_k= (1/2)^k y_0$ will be appreciated.

Comment: For clarification, is the equation in question written as $4y_{_{k+1}}  = 2y_{_k}$?

Comment: Yes it is.......

Comment: You need simply to iterate the relation $y_{k+1}=(1/2)y_k$:
$$y_1=(1/2) y_0$$
$$y_2=(1/2) y_1 = (1/2)^2 y_0$$
and so on, and you will see the solution rising from the pattern.

Comment: yk+1=(1/2)yk : can you please show the steps to this?

Comment: @GGGG I divided both sides of your original equation by $4$.

Comment: Ok, what about it being raised to the power ok K?

Comment: How do i get to the exact result yk=(1/2)ky0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y_{k+1}=\frac12y_k$$ so that

$$y_{1}=\frac12y_0$$

and

$$y_{2}=\frac12 y_1=\frac1{2^2}y_0$$

and

$$y_{3}=\frac12 y_2=\frac1{2^3}y_0$$
$$\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks! However, how can your equation be equal to the equation i wrote above? What about it being raised to the power of k

Comment: Please explain why your result is different from $y_k= (1/2)^k y_0$ ?

Comment: @GGGG: it is not different, look closely.

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand.....

Comment: @GGGG: come on, this is elementary algebra.

Comment: Im sorry but i do not get it.

Comment: Where do i take away the +1 and randomly add the k as an exponent