# How to re-write an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So I have this equation

$4y_{k+1} = 2y_k$.

If i divide both sides by 4, I get

$$y_{k+1}=\frac12y_k$$

However, the equation can be re-written as

so that

$$y_{1}=\frac12y_0$$

and

$$y_{2}=\frac12 y_1=\frac1{2^2}y_0$$

and

$$y_{3}=\frac12 y_2=\frac1{2^3}y_0$$
$$\cdots$$

This is a difference equation, where the initial condition first is y=0 and then y=2.

Can somebody please explain how , from $$y_{k+1}=\frac12y_k$$ i can get to the following equations?

Comment: Insert $k=0,1,2,\ldots$

Comment: If i do so, i get that y1=1 and y2=1 and these are not the answers, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Its a kind of following since i cant understand it really there...

Comment: "where the initial condition first is y=0 and then y=2. "  I do not understand this question.  Do you have a first term.  If $y_0 = a$ then this formula is simply $y_k = \frac 1{2^k} a$.  But you need a term.  If the term you are given is $y_m = a$ then the formula is $y_k = \frac 1{2^{k-m}}a = 2^{m-k} a$.

Comment: the question is : Solve the difference equation:
4yk+1 = 2yk first with the initial condition y0 = 0 and then with the initial condition
y0 = 2.

Comment: If you start with $y_0= 0$ then you get $y_1 = \frac 12*0 =$ and $y_2 = \frac 12 *0 = 0$ and so on.  $y_k = 0$.  If you start with $y_0 =1$ you get $y_1 = \frac 12 *1 = \frac 12$ and $y_2 = \frac 12*\frac 12 = \frac 14$ and so on. I don't understand what your problem is.  Why don't you just do what it says?

Comment: "he question is : Solve the difference equation: 4yk+1 = 2yk first with the initial condition y0 = 0 and then with the initial condition y0 = 2"  So.... just do it.  What exactly the problem you have?

Comment: Your question has already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018899/how-to-solve-a-difference-equation). Since your question is about the particular wording of that answer, you need to ask clarification commenting in the answer instead of asking a new question.

Comment: "If i do so, i get that y1=1 and y2=1"  Really?  Can you show us *how* got those weird answers".  "what am i doing wrong?" I have no idea because I do not know what you are doing at all. If you do what you said in your question you would not be getting those answers.

Comment: If i try and solve y1=(1/2)yo and y2=(1/2)^2yo. In order to apply the initial condiitons y0=0 and y0=2, is it fair to say that i should see a patter, which i see , which is yk=(1/2)^kyo. I then apply the different conditions to get the answers

Comment: Yes, that is the method. You will have two answers, one corresponding to $y_0=0$ and the other to $y_0=2$.

Comment: Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $$y_n={1\over 2}y_{n-1}={1\over 2^2}y_{n-2}={1\over 2^3}y_{n-3}=\cdots ={1\over 2^k}y_{n-k}$$let $k=n$ therefore $$y_n={1\over 2^n}y_0$$